# SwiftUI stop drag gesture amplification from scale

Tags: swiftui

The drag gesture works super great in swiftui when the scale of the object is `1.0`, but when that scale is larger or smaller than the drag gesture it no longer follows the natural movement of the users finger, but rather is amplified. In the below example I'm attempting to stop the amplification by dividing by the `scale` without any luck.

```
struct TestView: View {
@State var location1: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)
@State var newScale1: CGFloat = 5.0

var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            ColorSquare(color: .mint)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .position(location1)
                .scaleEffect(newScale1)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            self.location1 = value.location
                        }
                )
                .gesture (
                    MagnificationGesture()
                        .onChanged { gesture in
                            var scale = gesture/newScale1
                            self.newScale1 = scale
                        }
                )
}
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `translation`, which can be divided by your scale factor. But, you'll have to keep track of the start position:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var location: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
    @GestureState private var startLocation: CGPoint? = nil
    @State private var newScale1: CGFloat = 2.0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .position(location)
                .scaleEffect(newScale1)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            var newLocation = startLocation ?? location
                            newLocation.x += value.translation.width / newScale1
                            newLocation.y += value.translation.height  / newScale1
                            self.location = newLocation
                        }
                        .updating($startLocation) { (value, startLocation, transaction) in
                            startLocation = startLocation ?? location
                        }
                )
                .gesture (
                    MagnificationGesture()
                        .onChanged { gesture in
                            self.newScale1 = gesture / newScale1
                        }
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Adapted from: https://sarunw.com/posts/move-view-around-with-drag-gesture-in-swiftui/